# Using pragma once in .cpp file

Tags: c++, pragma

Recently reading some pieces of code I encountered several .cpp files that contained
`#pragma once` in the beginning of file. I know that it is usually used in .h files as guards.

What are the cases when `#pragma once` should/can/must be used in .cpp files?

Comment: Probably someone including *.cpp in a "Unity" (not the engine/SDK) build. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_build

Comment: For the **bad** cases when you include cpp files.

Comment: @RichardCritten: The Unity build should not include same files twice BTW (and the file including the cpp files is generated in those case, no?)

Comment: @Jarod42 Ouch. That's so nasty I didn't even think about it ;)

Comment: People not knowing what they are doing most likely

Comment: @Jarod42 ok re-enabled the answer, and added "normally" to it just for my ease of mind.

Comment: Most likely the author simply forgot to remove those when developing the application. Some devs first create a header file, then save it as .cpp for further modification. At that point it's easy to overlook that pragma.

Comment: There are no such cases in "normal" programming. The only person that knows why they are there in your case is the author.

Comment: @Jarod42 no it shouldn't; but just in-case I could see someone putting a `#pragma once` .

Comment: @RichardCritten Yes regrettably programmers can be very creative to satisfy a compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#pragma once` shouldn't be used in source files, its one goal is to act as include guard. It won't do much harm .cpp files are **normally** going to be "scanned" once during compilation anyway. Note: Clang tidy will warn you if you do it.

```
Warning clang-diagnostic-pragma-once-outside-header #pragma once in main file
```